# VB.NET How to NOT subtract a larger number from a smaller number for textBoxResult using random generated numbers

Tags: vb.net

Okay, so how do I do the part for display summary when i checked or unchecked?
Mine is not working for some reason. Am I missing out something? I have to give students the ability to control the display of the information.

Public Class MathPractice

```
Private Sub rbAddition_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbAddition.CheckedChanged
    'Change the label to plus
    lblPlus.Text = " + "
End Sub

Private Sub rbSubtraction_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbSubtraction.CheckedChanged
    'Change the label to minus        
    lblPlus.Text = "-"
    Dim intlbl1 As Integer = Val(lbl1.Text)
    Dim intlbl2 As Integer = Val(lbl2.Text)
    If rbSubtraction.Checked Then
        Do While intlbl1 < intlbl2
            If rbGrade1.Checked Then
                intlbl1 = Random.Next(1, 10)
            ElseIf rbGrade2.Checked Then
                intlbl1 = Random.Next(10, 99)
            End If
        Loop
        lbl1.Text = intlbl1.ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rbGrade1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbGrade1.CheckedChanged
    Dim random As New Random()
    'Get random numbers between 1 and 10.
    If rbGrade1.Checked Then
        lbl1.Text = random.Next(1, 10).ToString
        lbl2.Text = random.Next(1, 10).ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rbGrade2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbGrade2.CheckedChanged
    Dim random As New Random()
    random.Next(10, 99)
    'Get random numbers between 10 and 99.
    If rbGrade2.Checked Then
        lbl1.Text = random.Next(10, 99).ToString
        lbl2.Text = random.Next(10, 99).ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnCheckAnswer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckAnswer.Click
    'Check the answer whether it is right or wrong
    'Display a message box showing right or wrong
    Dim intlbl1 As Integer = Val(lbl1.Text)
    Dim intlbl2 As Integer = Val(lbl2.Text)
    Dim intResult As Integer = Val(txtBoxResult.Text)
    Dim btnCheckAnswer As String
    Select Case lblPlus.Text
        Case "+"
            If intResult = intlbl1 + intlbl2 Then
                btnCheckAnswer = "Correct."
            Else
                btnCheckAnswer = "Sorry. Try Again."
            End If
        Case "-"
            If intResult = intlbl1 - intlbl2 Then
                btnCheckAnswer = "Correct."
            Else
                btnCheckAnswer = "Sorry. Try Again."
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub chkBoxDisplaySummary_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBoxDisplaySummary.CheckedChanged
    'Display or hide information      
    If chkBoxDisplaySummary.Checked Then
        GroupBox2.Visible = True
    Else
        GroupBox2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You will get better response if you are able to show some code, that you have written so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok .. this should do it .. tho of course if the number in lbl2 is the biggest of the possible random numbers (10 or 99) lbl1 can never be bigger, so the code ive written could poddibly result in lbl1 and lbl2 both being 10 or 99. Anyhoe heres the code

ok ive recreated the app on my pc - there were a few errors in the original code that although it looked ok at a glance, threw things off - for example at the beginning when you assign a "+" to the lbl, you had a space either side of it, but in the checking answer logic there were no spaces. also cint on a string doesnt work when a visual studio opton called "option explicit" is turned on - having it on encourages better programming :) Also because of this "option explicit, you'll see ive added ".ToString in a few places as well

OK this is what ive got - i presume that your two sets of radio buttons are in two separate group boxes or the code would never have worked :)

have a look at the code below and compare it side by side with your original. Hope this helps. And dont forget the plus one if it does :-))

```
Private Sub rbAddition_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbAddition.CheckedChanged
    lblPlus.Text = "+"
End Sub

Private Sub rbSubtraction_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbSubtraction.CheckedChanged
    lblPlus.Text = "-"
    Dim intlbl1 As Integer = Val(lbl1.Text)
    Dim intlbl2 As Integer = Val(lbl2.Text)
    If rbSubtraction.Checked Then
        Do While intlbl1 < intlbl2
            If rbGrade1.Checked Then
                intlbl1 = random.Next(1, 10)
            ElseIf rbGrade2.Checked Then
                intlbl1 = random.Next(10, 99)
            End If
        Loop
        lbl1.Text = intlbl1.ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rbGrade1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbGrade1.CheckedChanged
    Dim random As New Random()
    'Get random numbers between 1 and 10.
    If rbGrade1.Checked Then
        lbl1.Text = random.Next(1, 10).ToString
        lbl2.Text = random.Next(1, 10).ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rbGrade2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbGrade2.CheckedChanged
    Dim random As New Random()
    random.Next(10, 99)
    'Get random numbers between 10 and 99.
    If rbGrade2.Checked Then
        lbl1.Text = random.Next(10, 99).ToString
        lbl2.Text = random.Next(10, 99).ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnCheckAnswer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckAnswer.Click
    Dim intlbl1 As Integer = Val(lbl1.Text)
    Dim intlbl2 As Integer = Val(lbl2.Text)
    Dim intResult As Integer = Val(txtboxResult.Text)
    Dim isTheAnswerCorrect As String
    Select Case lblPlus.Text
        Case "+"
            If intResult = intlbl1 + intlbl2 Then
                isTheAnswerCorrect = "Correct!"
            Else
                isTheAnswerCorrect = "Sorry. Try Again"
            End If
        Case "-"
            If intResult = intlbl1 - intlbl2 Then
                isTheAnswerCorrect = "Correct!"
            Else
                isTheAnswerCorrect = "Sorry. Try Again"
            End If
    End Select
    MsgBox(isTheAnswerCorrect)
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: OK. For the check answe button, i presume that once the random numbers are generated correctly - the user has to work out the addition or subtraction and type in the answer into the textbox. Based on this, ill add some code on the end of the above code in a few mins

Comment: I didnt want to mess with your original code too much, but it could do with shuffling around a bit and adding an extra button to do the number generation and checking rather than relying on changing states of the radio buttons. As it is, to generate a new number, you have to click on the unchecked grade box and maybe back to the original one if you want to carry on with the same grade of questions.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the insight and help.

Comment: My pleasure. I've been mucking around with visual basic on and off for years, and im not a pro by any means, but it's err fun passing on what i do know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if cint(lbl1.Text)>=cint(lbl2.Text) then
 intResult = cint(lbl1.Text)-cint(lbl2.Text) 
else
intResult = cint(lbl2.Text)-cint(lbl1.Text)
end if
```

Comment: That's not actually answer to the question as asked.  Also, it's rather inefficient at what it does do.

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt the user to calculate the difference between two numbers(without sign(+/-)). then you can do calculation using `Math.Abs()`

```
intResult = Math.Abs(Val(lbl1.Text)-Val(lbl2.Text))
```

Comment: i still cant use Mat.Abs because I havent learn it. but thanks for helping